# how to suppress the extra information in boost serialization::archive?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

In the example of Boost code of serialization
[bus schedule](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp)
in its output file "demofile.txt" the first line is:

```
"22 serialization::archive 16 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 6 24 4"
```

what is this?  Dll version number? Can we suppress this and store only the data itsself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a Dll version. It's the archive header.

Suppress it by using archive flags it:

```
void save_schedule(const bus_schedule &s, const char * filename){
    // make an archive
    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs, boost::archive::archive_flags::no_header);
    oa << s;
}
```

And remember to do the same on restoring, of course!

```
void restore_schedule(bus_schedule &s, const char * filename) {
    // open the archive
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs, boost::archive::archive_flags::no_header);

    // restore the schedule from the archive
    ia >> s;
}
```

See also

- [Boost binary archives - reducing size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807509/boost-binary-archives-reducing-size/45811396?s=1|47.7364#45811396)
- [Why does an non-intrusive serialization add a 5 byte zero prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608776/why-does-an-non-intrusive-serialization-add-a-5-byte-zero-prefix/47609367?s=5|34.0664#47609367)
- [Boost C++ Serialization overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459726/boost-c-serialization-overhead/22464553#22464553)